# How to revert to old 18.04 default theme

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, ambiance

I really would like to use the "old" 18.04 Ambiance theme in 20.04, but while I was able to get, install and set up the old GTK theme and  icons, I can't restore the gnome-shell theme and its correct behaviour (solid when windows are maximized, transparent when nothing touches it). Can somebody help?

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2588/fully-transparent-top-bar/

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is my panel doesn't show the usual gradient. It's just black when it's not transparent. Any idea?

Comment: you need to configure the panel via css file if that extension cannot offer gradient.. that is possible via css file..

Comment: I have a css taken from my old installation. The gradient is specified, but gnome-shell is ignoring it.

Comment: b0th are not compatible 18.04 css n 20.04 css.. in 20.04 r u looking for gradient when maximzed n transparent when not maximzed?? it is possible..

Comment: if your current css is working for 20.04 n u want to achieve gradient.. plz link that css n I will try to workout..